# Варианты адаптации трехколоночного макета

Tags: html, css

Есть макет, состоящий из основного контента и сайдбаров с виджетами по бокам (3 колонки).

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside {
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

main {
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  aside {
    width: 25%;
  }
  
  .left {
    float: left;
  }

  .right {
    float: right;
  }
  
  main {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <aside class="left">
    
  </aside>
  
  <main>
    
  </main>
  
  <aside class="right">
    
  </aside>
</div>
```

При мобильной версии сайдбары с виджетами просто выравниваю по центру и вид получается не особо приятный, много места свободного.

**Вопрос:** какие есть варианты адаптации подобного трехколоночного макета?

P.S: видела всего один вариант реализации, который заключается в скрытии виджетов, начиная с планшета и до мобильных телефонов, т.е. остается только основной контент. Вариант логичный и красивый, но может быть есть еще варианты.

Comment: Под свободным местом подразумевается пустота по бокам у aside? aside ряастянуть на всю ширину не вариант?

Comment: А почему не flexbox верстаете?

Comment: @Cheg, да по бокам aside,  а если растягивать как-то "жирно" получается, в виджетах превью галереии огромными кажутся. В принципе как вариант.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, можно и флексами, вопрос в возможных вариантах. Не верстаю  в основном из-за поддержки, есть проблемы на некоторых девайсах с отображением

Comment: Если например флексами, то как понимаю расположить основной контент, а после него поставить эти сайдбары ...

Comment: @HamSter А можно картинками желаемого результата поделиться? А то из разметки с фиксированными величинами неясно, что надо. Ну или текстом пояснить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если содержимое `aside` позволяет растянуть его без потери эстетического вида, можно растянуть эти самые `aside` на всю ширину экрана:

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside {
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  aside {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .left {
    float: left;
  }
  .right {
    float: right;
  }
  main {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <aside class="left">

  </aside>

  <main>

  </main>

  <aside class="right">

  </aside>
</div>
```

---

Если же такой вариант не подходит, можно немного изменить структуру страницы и поиграть с `float`:

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

aside.left {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  clear: both;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  aside {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .left {
    float: left;
  }
  .right {
    float: right;
  }
  main {
    clear: none;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <aside class="left">

  </aside>

  <aside class="right">

  </aside>

  <main>

  </main>
</div>
```

---

Ну, а если менять структуру совсем не хочется, можно сделать на flexbox и менять порядок следования `order`:

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 250px;
}

aside.left {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
  order: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: block;
  }
  aside {
    width: 25%;
    min-width: auto;
  }
  .left {
    float: left;
  }
  .right {
    float: right;
  }
  main {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <aside class="left">

  </aside>

  <main>

  </main>

  <aside class="right">

  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: И еще как вариант `aside` задать `order:2` чтобы контент выше был, а обе колонки внизу под ним. Спасибо!

Comment: @HamSter Как вариант, да. Все зависит от требований. Бывают случаи, что контент в каком-то из сайдбаров должен быть заметным и отображаться первым.