# Поменять местами столбцы при уменьшении разрешения?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">Тут текст</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Тут изображение</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При уменьшения разрешения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Как видно при маленьком разрешении col-sm-9 становится первым, а за ним col-sm-3, но мне нужно что бы при уменьшении разрешения до мобильного(768), col-sm-3 становился первым, а за ним был col-sm-9. Сделал два col-sm-3: первый - col-sm-3 visible-xs, второй - col-sm-3 hidden-xs. Такой способ работает, но хотелось бы узнать более изящный способ решить данный вопрос, так-как то что я использую загружает дважды одну и туже картинку.

Comment: С bootstrap не особо знаком, но если там используется flexbox, то почитайте про свойство order

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699022/209956 - вот тут я расписывал несколько вариантов того, как можно решить данную задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо поменять колонки местами и добавить к колонкам классы `..-pull/push-..`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">Тут изображение</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">Тут текст</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[В документации](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering) есть исчерпывающий ответ на ваш вопрос, каким образом менять местами колонки на разных экранах

Answer (score 0):

Следайте так: используйте `.col-md-9` для `md-разрешения` и `sm` для `sm-разрешения`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, voluptatum dolores suscipit maiores et, voluptas deleniti rem magni sed dolore non placeat nihil id doloribus consectetur odit ratione quia nulla!</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-9 col-xs-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos optio rem, nihil sint id nam ipsam suscipit! Dolor consequatur eum reiciendis. Reiciendis fugiat autem vero labore a dicta est rem.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```